# How to create simple simulaton code using classes

Tags: python, shopping-cart

I want to create simple simulation code using classes like:

```
product_list = []
price = []
barcode = ["banana": 123 , "apple": 234 , "orange": 345 , "pear": 456 ]
```

I want to add product in cart by using their representative number and sum up added product price.

Example: If the user enters `123` then `banana` need to add in list and price of banana should add in price list.

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a python dictionary.

**Ex:**

```
barcode = {"banana": 123 , "apple": 234 , "orange": 345 , "pear": 456 }
barcode = dict((v,k) for k,v in barcode.items())    #-->Reverse Key -Value
v = 123

product_list = []
price = []    

product_list.append(barcode[123])
price.append(123)

print(product_list)
print(price)
```